# Iterating through Perl collection, calculating new value

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have a Perl script which has the following line in it:

```
print $_->{label} || $_->{irq}, "=", $_->{count}, "; " for @irqs;
```

Where `@irqs` is some kind of collection (I am not a Perl programmer) that is `push`ed to elsewhere in the program.

I have another collection which is a hash, where the key is equal to either the value of `$_->{label}`or `$_->{irq}` from the collection `@irqs`.

Instead of printing `$_->{count}` in the above statement, I would like to print `$_->{count} - X` where `X` is the value from the hash.

I am sure that I can do this by iterating through `@irqs` by hand and pushing either `$_->{label}`or `$_->{irq}` onto a new collection with the calculated value, but, is there a better way to do it?

As I said, I'm not a Perl programmer, so I just wanted to make sure I was going down the correct path before starting out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to copy/store any additional data to do this.

```
foreach my $irq (@irqs) {
    my $key = $irq->{label} || $irq->{irq};
    print $key, "=", $irq->{count} - $myhash{$key}, "; ";
}
```